# Google Bigquery query execution using google cloud dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to execute Bigquery's query using Google cloud data flow directly and fetch data, not reading data from table then putting conditions?

For example, PCollections res=p.apply(BigqueryIO.execute("Select col1,col2 from publicdata:samples.shakeseare where ...."))

Instead of reinventing using iterative method what Bigquery queries already implemented, we can use the same directly.

Thanks and Regards

Ajay K N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQueryIO currently only supports reading from a Table and not a Query or View ([FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#question-13)).

One way to work around this is in your main program to create a BigQuery [permanent table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data) by issuing a query before you run your Dataflow job. After, your job runs you could delete the table.